# awk: get log data part by part

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

the log file is

```
Oct 01 [time] a
Oct 02 [time] b
Oct 03 [time] c
.
.
.
Oct 04 [time] d
Oct 05 [time] e
Oct 06 [time] f
.
.
.
Oct 28 [time] g
Oct 29 [time] h
Oct 30 [time] i
```

and it is really **big** ( millions of lines )

I wanna to get logs between `Oct 01` and `Oct 30`

I can do it with gawk

```
gawk 'some conditions' filter.log
```

and it works correctly.

and it return millions of log lines that is not good

because I wanna to get it **part by part**

some thing like this

```
gawk 'some conditions' -limit 100 -offset 200 filter.log
```

and every time when I change `limit` and `offset`

I can get another part of that.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

**awk solution**
I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and say I want to print such lines that 1st field is odd in part starting at 3th line and ending at 7th line (inclusive), then I can use GNU `AWK` following way

```
awk 'NR<3{next}$1%2{print}NR>=7{exit}' file.txt
```

which will give

```
3
5
7
```

Explanation: `NR` is built-in variable, which hold **n**umber of **r**ow, when processing lines before `3` just go to `next` row without doing anything, when remainder from division by 2 is non-zero do `print` line, when processing 7th or further row just `exit`. Using `exit` might give notice boost in performance if you are processing relatively small part of file. Observe order of 3 pattern-action pairs in code above: `next` is first, then whatever you do want do, `exit` is last. If you want to know more about `NR` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

**linux solution**
If you prefer working with offset limit, then you might exploit tail-head combination e.g. for above `file.txt`

```
tail -n +5 file.txt | head -3
```

gives output

```
5
6
7
```

observe that offset goest first and with `+` before value then limit with `-` before value.

Comment: I think awk solution will not work because it limit input line NOT output lines

Comment: I think linux solution is better way

Answer (score 1):

Using OP's pseudo code mixed with some actual `awk` code:

```
gawk -v limit=100 -v offset=200 '
some conditions { matches++                                # track number of matches
                  if (matches >= offset and limit > 0) {
                     print                                 # print current line
                     limit--                               # decrement limit
                  }
                  if (limit == 0) exit                     # optional: abort processing if we found "limit" number of matches
                }
' filter.log
```